# Internet Explorer iconfont problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-size, webfonts, icon-fonts

I have a little problems with icon webfont and IE. 
With Chrome, the font-size:1.3em is correctly displayed. 
But with IE, the font-size isn't respected (in px and in em...).

I have tested a font-size in em and px.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtV84.png

```
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before, [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

the header.php's file where are the icons : http://pastebin.com/4kcTy5ew

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you put in the main html? i think the problem isnt in the code you posted

Comment: Please make a fiddle

Comment: Its so much easier for people to help

Comment: I can't, the file is in php and must import the webfont ...

Comment: AH sorry, did not see that

Comment: My gues would be that there is a tag not closed

Comment: The validator indicates 0 errors ...

Comment: Thats Strange, it could be a bug. I've read somewhere that you can use a reset css file